# How to keep custom checkbox and label in same scalable, relative position

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently using this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp) as a template for my checkbox input style and I'm very pleased with it on the whole. There is a very big problem though that the label/checkmark isn't attached to the checkbox cell itself, and fixed/relative positioning has been applied which assumes that the screen size/scale doesn't change. I need these elements to realign themselves together, at the same time, whenever the scale/size of the viewport changes. My code is below. Thanks in advance to any and all help, as always!

HTML/React.js file:

```
 render() {
    const styles = require('./checkbox.scss');
    return (
      <div className={styles.checkbox}>
        <div id="cbArray">
          <div id="confInput">
            <div id="chkLabel"><h3>I understand this</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div id="cbComp">
            <input type="checkbox" ref="chkBox1" id="test1" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label htmlFor="test1"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

CSS:

```
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 17px; height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}
```

Comment: This is not a Sass or ReactJS problem.

Comment: Change this `<label htmlFor="test1"></label>` to `<label for="test1"></label>`

Comment: @divy3993, react doesn't recognize that attribute as `for`, I needed to change it to `htmlFor` in order to compile

Comment: Oh, then it might not be possible.